# Hault the execution

Tags: javascript, php

I have a timer on my page, as timer expires it is prompting alertbox, now the problem is even after pressing OK button in alertbox it is calling again and again. Actually, I wants to redirect it to another page.
`window.location="";` will work but it is going in minus timer.

HTML CODE:

```
<div>Registration closes in <span id="time">00:03</span> minutes</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT CODE:

```
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"   integrity="sha256-slogkvB1K3VOkzAI8QITxV3VzpOnkeNVsKvtkYLMjfk="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>  

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.text(minutes + ":" + seconds);

        if (--timer < 0) {
            alert("I am an alert box!");
            //window.location = "http://www.google.com";
        }
    }, 1000);
}

jQuery(function ($) {
    var fiveMinutes = 0.5 * 5,
        display = $('#time');
    startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
});
    </script>
```

Comment: Where exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You has to save the reference of your interval to stop it when you want it. Take a look this:

```js
var interval;
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    interval = setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.text(minutes + ":" + seconds);

        if (--timer < 0) {
            alert("I am an alert box!");
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 1000);
}

$(function ($) {
    var fiveMinutes = 0.5 * 5,
        display = $('#time');
    startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js" integrity="sha256-slogkvB1K3VOkzAI8QITxV3VzpOnkeNVsKvtkYLMjfk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>  
<div id="time" />
```

But It will prefer to use this code

```
setTimeout(function(){ startTimer(fiveMinutes, display); }, 1000);
```

and then into startTimer function, depending on your logic, call again the setTimeout.

Hope It helps!

Comment: Perfect! Thanks Mate!'

Comment: `interval` doesn't need to be a global variable, since you're calling `clearInterval` inside the same function that started it.

Answer (score 1):

Clear the interval when you are done using it: [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval)

```
var timerHandle = setInterval(function () {
/* ... code ...*/
if (--timer < 0) {
    clearInterval(timerHandle);
    alert("I am an alert box!");
    //window.location = "http://www.google.com";
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval()` will return an identifier, which you should assign to a variable.

To stop the interval function from being called, you need to `clearInterval()`.

Your code should look like this:

```
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"   integrity="sha256-slogkvB1K3VOkzAI8QITxV3VzpOnkeNVsKvtkYLMjfk="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>  

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    myInterval = setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.text(minutes + ":" + seconds);

        if (--timer < 0) {
            alert("I am an alert box!");
            clearInterval(myInterval);
            //window.location = "http://www.google.com";
        }
    }, 1000);
}

jQuery(function ($) {
    var fiveMinutes = 0.5 * 5,
        display = $('#time');
    startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
});
    </script>
```